# If clause launches exception

Tags: ios, if-statement

I have following if statement.

```
if ([sec isEqualToString:@"0"] && [quitar isEqualToString:@"si" ] && [ numObjectsSec0 > 1 ] ){
            NSLog(@"SE PODRIA QUITAR ESTE OBJETO"); 
        }

sec is a NSString variable
quitar is a NSString variable
numObjectsSecO is an int variable
```

I am getting a compiler error at the third component: `[ numObjectsSec0 > 1 ]`

```
Error: Expected identifier
```

Sorry for the stupid question, but I am handling with it for an hour...

Comment: The brackets `[]` are used for sending a message to an object. It looks like you’re just making a comparison. If you replace the brackets with parentheses, like `(numObjectsSec0 > 1)`, does it do what you want?

Comment: BTW - that is not "launching an exception". It is simply a compiler error. Exceptions happen at runtime, not build time.

Comment: @bdesham You don't need parentheses either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[ numObjectsSec0 > 1 ]`, use `(numObjectsSec0 > 1)`, remove the `[]`. Those are only for function calls.

Comment: There is no need for parentheses here.

Comment: You are right @rmaddy, it works with parentheses and without parentheses, the only problem were the brackets.

Comment: You are right @rmaddy, I figured that he was trying to make his code easy to read with the `[]`, but messed up.